# Why static content from maven dependency served in spring-boot?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a simple multimodule maven project. The first module is angular frontend, the second module is spring-boot application.

I configured frontend maven module to build angular application and collect assembled files into `frontend.jar`. As result, I have the following archive structure:

```
jar -tf frontend.jar | sort
---------------------------
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/sample-project/
META-INF/maven/sample-project/frontend/
META-INF/maven/sample-project/frontend/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/sample-project/frontend/pom.xml
static/
static/3rdpartylicenses.txt
static/assets/
static/assets/img/
static/assets/img/loading.gif
static/favicon.png
static/index.html
static/main.8e44da4898d2a7a95ed3.js
static/polyfills.d72edd4c76dc8f27444a.js
static/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js
static/styles.0afb74a990d73ad0b544.css
```

After that, I add to the spring-boot `.pom` file dependency on frontend module and build whole project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, than I started spring boot web application, I discovered, that when I go to `localhost:port/` url I get my angular application.

The question is the next: how spring-boot understood that it should serve static content from `frontend` dependency? Note, that I don't have static folder in spring-boot module resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, "jars" are just way of organizing application for deployment. You cannot address classes or resources based on their actual jars or location on disk (unless you are writing your own `ClassLoader`). Such physical details are not available in runtime. From the runtime perspective everything is flattened, a bit like docker layers.

So, there really is no notion of "which class comes from which dependency". This sometimes leads to subtle errors, but is also the reason of existence of technologies like jarjar, OSGi and the new Java 9 modules.

Spring Boot, generally, serves everything that's available in classpath under /static. There is no notion of "which jar" or "which directory" the resources come from.